# Вывести поле ACF WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Есть страница, где я списком вывожу посты с `post_type=test` . На этой странице мне нужно вывести кастомное поле `text_area` конкретного поста, известен его id, и у него другой `post_type=areas`. Первой мыслью было сделать через WP_Query, однако вывод в принципе прекращался. Как можно поступить?

```
 $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'areas', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
    if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
        echo '<pre>' . get_field('text_area') . '</pre>';
      endwhile;
    }
// дальше вывод постов
global $query_string; 
$thePosts = query_posts($query_string.'&'.$order);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  get_template_part('loop'); ?>
 endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Вывод прекращался в нижнем цикле? В верхнем цикле вы забыли сделать `wp_reset_postdata();`. Не совсем понял почему вверху `WP_Query`, а внизу `query_posts`. И в `get_field()` [можно передать ID записи](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), я так понимаю что это каким-то образом может избавить вас от верхнего цикла.

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но всё же. Забудьте, что такая функция как `query_posts` существует. Она не для вас, а для ядра, там много своих особенностей. Используйте только WP_Query или `get_posts`.

Comment: Всем спасибо!) Кстати передача id в get_field действительно закрыла мой вопрос